# Translating canvas-lms api cURL request to HttpWebRequest

Tags: curl, httpwebrequest, canvas-lms

When I try sending the request I get an "Internal Error" exception, so I want to know if the problem is in my specific request, or if there is an issue beyond that.

The cUrl request looks like this:

> curl https://(canvas_api_url)?access_token=(access-token)
>
> -X POST
>
> -F 'enrollment[user_id]=241'
>
> -F 'enrollment[type]=StudentEnrollment'

My request looks like this:

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://<canvas_api_url>?access_token=<access-token>");

req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = " application/json; charset=utf-8";
req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredential;

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream())
{
     string json = "{\"enrollment\" : 
     [\"user_id\" : \"241\", \"type\" : \"StudentEnrollment\"]}";
     streamWriter.Write(json);
}

HttpWebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

Is there something wrong with my request?

Answer (score 0):

I see this post is pretty old, but here's some thoughts based on a quick look at it. You don't say what you're trying to accomplish, so there's a couple potential mistakes here:

1. If you're requesting an existing enrollment, you should be using GET instead of POST.
2. If you're trying to create a new enrollment, you haven't structured the endpoint right - you need to specify a course (/api/v1/courses/:course_id/enrollments) and then you can include the `user_id` and the `type`.

The specifics are listed in the docs here: https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/enrollments.html